# Ruby passing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the proper way to pass the parameters to a function?

For example:

```
 def self.find_by_example(username, email)
   user = User.find_by_username(username) || User.find_by_email(email)
 end
```

I would like to find the user by his `username` or `email` but if a create a function passing the 2 parameters Rails shows

> (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))

When I call `User.find_by_example('example')`

I still don't get it, the parameters passed in must not be the attribute?
and why does it say "given 1"?

Comment: can you show how you call this function?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is figure out what line is causing the error. Most likely when your method is called, only 1 parameter is given, so you need to look at the code that calls your method and ensure it always passes 2 parameters. It could also be that it's failing on some other line which is throwing you off. Ultimately you need to provide more information if someone is going to help you figure it out.

Comment: @meta, i call User.find_by_exemple('exemple')

Comment: @radixhound was just this line the is causing the error, but as i'm learning i created this exemple to understand how to pass the parameters to the function

Comment: The problem is in how you call the method. Somehow, it seems you are only passing one argument, but have defined the method to take two parameters. Unfortunately, you don't show the part of the code where you are calling the method, so there is no way that we can possibly help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be calling the function like `User.find_by_example("name to find") and the function expects two arguments (name and email). You could define the function as:

```
def self.find_by_example(term)
  user = User.find_by_username(term) || User.find_by_email(term)
end
```

And call it `User.find_by_example("Name to find")` or `User.find_by_example("email@to_find.com")`

This does not work ok if you have users with a username like an email. And it is not much efficient if you wish to search by other fields. SO you could also:

```
def self.find_by_example(terms)
  if terms[:email]
    user = User.find_by_email(terms[:email])
  elsif terms[:username]
    user = User.find_by_username(terms[:username])
  elsif terms[:id]
    user = User.find_by_id(terms[:id])
  elsif terms[:document]
    user = User.find_by_document(terms[:document])
  end
end
```

And call the method `User.find_by_example(:email => "email@example.com")`. This is similar to the `find_by` method that Active Record already provides (but allows many arguments), so no need to implement it.

Comment: What happens when you have `user_1` with `username = 'email@to_find.com'` and `email = 'foo@bar.com'` and `user_2` with `username = 'foo@bar.com'` and `email = 'email@to_find.com'` and you call `User.find_by_example('email@to_find.com')`?

Comment: In the latter case, why have a new function? Why not just do `User.find_by(email: 'email@example.com')`?

Comment: @Pablo thank you, but one of my doubts is why must not use the attibute as the parameters?
and should be just 1 when the function have a conditional?

Comment: You know what happens :). Just showing lula the possible error in the way she is calling the function and showing different ways to pass parameters, as she asked.

Comment: Oh, this makes my heart weep.

Comment: Pablo, thank you, i'm starting to understand, so in this case, you did not pass the parameter name but just a reference?

Comment: While you're at it, you might as well discuss how to handle `nil` cases (like, `User.find_by_example` - with no parameters).

Comment: In the first case I'm passing one parameter (a string) and the function will use it as a name and as an email (it will do the find_by twice with this parameter, if the first find does not work). In the second case, I'm also passing one parameter, but this time it is a hash. Depending on the keys in the hash, the function will do the corresponding find_by.

Comment: This `if..elseif` code can be improved if you just call `find_by(email: 'foo')`. I'm pretty sure `find_by_WHATEVER_FIELD` methods are discouraged or even deprecated in current rails.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed and accepted answer is not really the equivalent of the code asked in the question. It is accepted, so one might assume that it guessed the OP intent correctly. But I think it can be useful for (especially junior) programmers to think about the problem more deeply.

## Think of what method should do

(not just if it immediately gives you result you wish to see, there can be surprises in the edge cases)

The original code

```
def self.find_by_example(username, email)
  user = User.find_by_username(username) || User.find_by_email(email)
end
```

Could be used this way `x.find_by_example(nil, 'test@example.com')`. 
If we assume there can't be users with NULL `username` (which IMO is a reasonable assumption), the call would result in finding an user strictly by `email`.

The proposed solution does not give you this possibility:

```
def self.find_by_example(term)
  user = User.find_by_username(term) || User.find_by_email(term)
end
```

`x.find_by_example('test@example.com')` would return user with such username if exists, and (possibly other) user with such e-mail otherwise.

In other words - you have less control which field is used to find a user (which can be correct, if that's really what you need)

So it depends on the OP intent.

If one want to retain how the original method works, but improve the interface, it could be done like this:

```
def self.find_by_example2(username: nil, email: nil)
  user = User.find_by_username(username) || User.find_by_email(email)
end
```

And calling `x.find_by_example2(email: 'test@example.com')` is equivalent to `x.find_by_example(nil, 'test@example.com')` but looks better.

## Bonus: Performance implications

The proposed solution

```
def self.find_by_example(term)
  user = User.find_by_username(term) || User.find_by_email(term)
end
```

makes second query when the user is not find by `username`. You can improve it as well if you wish to employ some sql magic:

```
def self.find_by_example(term)
  user = User.where("username = ? OR (username IS NULL and email = ?)", term, term).first
end
```

There's another possibility (though not 100% equivalent to the accepted solution):

```
def self.find_by_example(term)
  user = User.where("username = ? OR email = ?", term, term).first
end
```

(I'll leave as an exercise the answer how those are different, to keep this post short...ish)

## Bonus 2: flexibility

This

```
def self.find_by_example(terms)
  if terms[:email]
    user = User.find_by_email(terms[:email])
  elsif terms[:username]
    user = User.find_by_username(terms[:username])
  elsif terms[:id]
    user = User.find_by_id(terms[:id])
  elsif terms[:document]
    user = User.find_by_document(terms[:document])
  end
end
```

is a waste of your time, because rails gives you already better interface to do this.

Instead of calling

```
x.find_by_example(document: 'foo')
```

you could just do

```
User.find_by(document: 'foo')
```

There's really no need to implement it that way, it's basically crippled version of ActiveRecord interface, that you have to maintain as you add new fields to `User` model.

Comment: thank you for your contribution, i found that has a lot of way to solve this too. but, my first doubt in this case was about the parameters. which Pablo clarified me as i understood, that was not about pass the attributes itself but a reference to it.